# JBoss EAP6 - restart multiple hosts with one command in domain mode

Tags: jboss, command-line-interface, jboss-eap-6

I have an app that needs to be restarted through the `JBoss CLI` on multiple hosts during a deployment.

Is there a way to do this dynamically with a single `restart(blocking=true)` command? Or is there a different command that restarts all hosts while also using the `blocking` argument that waits for the servers restart.

**Example code**

```
/host=devserver1/server-config=Group-devserver1:restart(blocking=true)
/host=devserver2/server-config=Group-devserver2:restart(blocking=true)
/host=devserver3/server-config=Group-devserver3:restart(blocking=true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the server group to restart the servers with blocking or you can restart the servers on the host, but there is no blocking.

To restart via the server group you'd do something like:

```
/server-group=main-server-group:restart-servers(blocking=true)
```

To restart on the host you'd do something like:

```
/host=master:reload(restart-servers=true)
```

Comment: I've tried using the above command for the server-group and this is my result:`Operation 'restart-servers' does not expect any property.`

Comment: My apologies. I missed the jboss-eap-6 tag. That parameter wasn't included until EAP 7. So you could reload the servers there it just wouldn't block the management client.